# How to reduce number of arguments in my Symfony2 service?

Tags: symfony

I am building an invoiceManager for my application. It is essentially my model for my Invoice entity.

I use it as a service.

The problem is I feel it __construct need too much arguments.

Right now it is like this :

```
function __construct($invoiceRepo, $clientRepo, $em, $templating) {
   $this->invoiceRepo = $invoiceRepo;
   $this->clientRepo  = $clientRepo;
   $this->em          = $em;
   $this->templating  = $templating;
}
```

The problem is than I need to access some YML parameters now and the solution I found is adding a fifth argument to the constructor.

I feel this is not the proper way to do but I can't find the right solution to build slimmer service.

How would you do ? What are the best practices ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what's wrong with passing too many arguments and why do you need to keep the service slim? keeping the controllers slim is a recommended practice, but there is no rule that says services have to be slim, in fact they have to be fat IMO, the code has to go somewhere, it all comes down to segregating it into manageable chunks, i see no problem here.

Comment: Inject whole container and you'll have one argument. Happy?

Comment: I would eliminate the $em by adding persist/commit methods to my repos.  I kind of wonder if it makes sense for a manager type service to do templating.  In any event, some of the Symfony services have 8-10 args so I would not worry too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of alternatives to accomplish that

1) you could inject just the Entity Manager then get the repositories inside the constructor. And get rid of 2 arguments ($clientRepo, $invoiceRepo). Something like this:

```
__construct( $em, $templating) {
      $invoiceRepo = $em->getRepository('InvoiceRepo');
      $clientRepo = $em->getRepository('ClientRepo);
      // ...
}
```

2) you can inject the service via setters and reduce the number of constructor's arguments

in `services.yml`

```
    my.service:
     class: AppBundle\Manager\MyManager
      arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
      calls:
        - [setMyService1, [@my.service1] ]
        - [setMyService2, [@my.service2] ]
```

in `AppBundle\Manager\MyManager`

```
// ...
public function setMyService1($service) {
   $this->myService1 = $service;
}

public function setMyService1($service) {
   $this->myService1 = $service;
}

// ...
```

I would not recommend injecting the whole container into the service. Beside other reasons this practice make the class less testable.

Answer (score 0):

Many others services in your own service symfony it's not a problem for many reason :

- container aware is implementing for use a Dependency Injection with kind of singleton pattern for instance of service
- also you don't use a arguments service in your service, the performance application don't downgrade because the service is assuredly already instancied
- lot of service use lot of service. For all of those services, symfony don't create for each service all of this arguments as instance.  SF mutualize all the call for the same service

A good and simpliest practice is to use the container in service which able to launch all others services you need (as say @malcolm)

**BUT (and perhaps)**

You can review the structure of your code for chain your responsability instead of cut up to extrem atomic function.

*service A need service B need service C*

in place of

*service A AND service B AND service C in a same other service.*

Finally, and this is just a different reflexion, It's not necessary to always implement all of logic in services. 
Ok service is good practice
Ok controller smaller is good
But all logic in service just for look good and respect good practice is not a good practice.

Optimization is a very very difficult and widely discuss. If a unique solution exist which run anytime in any place all developers know that and no discuss necessary... You must balance your reflexion with all this practice and test that.

Comment: I just want to correct that injecting full container is not a good practice, I suggested that with sarcasm.